# Loading packages with TexMaker

Tags: miktex, texmaker, miktex-update

I am using MikTeX 2.9 with TexMaker 5.1.2 as a front end.  When a LaTeX file asks for a package, a dialog box for "Proxy Authentication" pops up asking for a "Name" and a "Password".  I have been unable to find a way to put in a name and a password.  What is the story?

Comment: It's probably MikTeX trying to install missing package (it has the ability to install packages on the fly). Save yourself the headache (I've seen this feature fail or behave badly too many times), install what you need in advance in the MikTeX console or, better, install everything. That's what TeX Live does by default, and it's far simpler afterwards.